# GitHub: Can't find remote repository after re-installation

Tags: git, bash, repository, reinstall

I've re-installed the git bash. And when I tried to clone from one of my private repository, I was told that

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<MY REPO ADDRESS>/' not found
```

I've checked that my username and email were all correct using the command

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Why couldn't git find the repository? Is it because I forgot to configure something else?

Here is a snapshot of the command line:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user.name and user.email have nothing to do with https authentication.
The former is for commits, the latter uses the GitHub username and password.

Since I don't see a debugging.git repo in [your repo page](https://github.com/neolicd?tab=repositories), it could be a private repo (in which case double-check the username and password you should have to enter when cloning it).
Or it does not exist (in which case, [create it on GitHub first](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/))

Comment: Yes, it is a private repo. And after I explicitly add my username and password to the url when cloning it. Everything works well afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well done! On Windows, you can use a cache for the password: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40036992/6309